# Причина возникновения ошибки ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Мой код:

```
SELECT sn.name pokupatel, d.dil_name prodavec, p.name eda, pl.price cena, 
sp.dat date, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity) pokupki
FROM products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp, saleman sn, dilers d
WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND pl.dat = sp.dat AND sp.men_pers_code = sn.men_pers_code AND sn.n_dil = d.n_dil
GROUP BY pokupatel, prodavec, eda, cena, date, sp.quantity
ORDER BY prodavec, pokupki DESC;
```

При запуске этого кода у меня вылезает ошибка

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Обшарил весь код, ничего не смог найти. Знатоки, помогите пожалуйста.

Я учёл ответ одного из ответчиков о том, что date это зарезервированное слово.
Заменил это слово. В итоге у меня получился вот такой код:

```
SELECT sn.name pokupatel, d.dil_name prodavec, p.name eda, pl.price cena, 
sp.dat mydate, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity) pokupki
FROM products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp, saleman sn, dilers d
WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND pl.dat = sp.dat AND sp.men_pers_code = sn.men_pers_code AND sn.n_dil = d.n_dil
GROUP BY pokupatel, prodavec, eda, cena, mydate, sp.quantity
ORDER BY prodavec, pokupki DESC;
```

При запуске этого кода у меня теперь почему-то вылезает ошибка:

```
ORA-00904: "MYDATE": invalid identifier
```

НО! Самое интересное то, что если я не использую замену значений - запрос работает.

```
SELECT sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity)
FROM products p, pricelist pl, salemap sp, saleman sn, dilers d
WHERE p.prod_id = pl.prod_id AND pl.dat = sp.dat AND sp.men_pers_code = sn.men_pers_code AND sn.n_dil = d.n_dil
GROUP BY sn.name, d.dil_name, p.name, pl.price, sp.dat, sp.quantity
ORDER BY d.dil_name, (count(sn.men_pers_code) * sp.quantity) DESC;
```

Почему так?

Comment: Теперь вы можете убрать дополнение, так как это не относится напрямую к текущему вопросу. Если вы не найдёте более подробный ответ по метке [sql] и ключевым словам - "alias видимость", то просто задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что `DATE` зарезервированное слово, и так не работает:

```sql
select (sysdate+rownum) date from dual;
```

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

, а так будет:

```sql
select (sysdate+rownum) mydate from dual;  

MYDATE             
-------------------
2019-09-14 00:13:36
```

Comment: Я дополнил запрос. Там кое-какая интересная ситуация. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ничего странного, алиасы не известны в group by.

Comment: То есть алиасы нельзя использовать 'GROUP BY'?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, только в order by.